# Opportunity details page shows blank page from salesforce community?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I am using the below link in my lightning component to view the opportunity record details view .
this will be working fine from developer console but if the community user login to the community after clicking the 
Opportunity id link it redirected to the blank page.

Anybody having the idea on this.

this link is executed from developer console and redirected to the opportunity record details page:

```
    <a href="{! '/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ opp.Id + '/view'}">{!opp.Id }</a>

    this is the redirected url from developer console :  https://xxxxxxxxxx.force.com/one/one.app?#/sObject/0061I000003oj8gQAA/view
```

The same link returns the blank page by executing from salesforce community.

This is redirected url and returns blank page :

https://sftestcommunities-developer-edition.na73.force.com/one/one.app?#/sObject/0061I000002UW1EQAW/view

Comment: Can the Community user access the Opportunity record OK? I mean is the Profile and Sharing set to allow him/her to see it? What's the type of the community? From what I remember partner license users can see Opportunities but Customers - no way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a Salesforce PATH, from a community domain. You need to create a community page for manage opportunities. And the link must go to opportunity communities page.